# Why does Ubuntu's boot become slower with the passing of time?

Tags: boot

I'm 3 years into using Ubuntu as my default OS, but I notice that Ubuntu is becoming slower after some weeks of installation.  On all the Ubuntu versions I have used including "Ubuntu 10.10, 11.04, 11.10 and 12.04", the boot becomes slower. When I make a fresh install, it boots in just 17 seconds... after 2 mouths, the system takes almost 1 minute to boot (Slower than Win7). I tried to disable all the software that starts with the System, but the problem continues (I had this problem with my older notebook, so it's not hardware related).

Ubuntu's boot looks inconsistent too, because sometimes I see the purple boot screen, sometimes I just can see an underline at the left-top side of screen. 
So. Why is Ubuntu's boot going slower with time?  Can it be fixed?

Comment: I've been using Ubuntu since 2008 and I've Never had bootup time increase with age. Though I have seen weird looking boot screens before. Perhaps your system is running filesystem checks during bootup?

Comment: Same here, boot time increases with age of installation:(

Answer (score 2):

Depending on the applications you install these can all affect boot time.

It is an easy thing to diagnoise just install

```
sudo apt-get install bootchart
```

After you install and reboot look in /var/log/bootchart and evaluate your data.

Answer (score 0):

Anything that installs as a system service will be loaded every time you boot.  This includes things like the MySQL server, Apache server or any other server processes that install themselves system-wide.

If you have installed a lot of software like this it is going to affect boot time a bit.